# PWA interoperability with Android apps/services?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

We know that some of our code must be in native code, but it can be encapsulated as an Android service. We would like to create the UI-oriented part as a progressive web app (PWA).

Is there a way for the PWA to interact with native apps on the device (e.g., call them with parameters and handle replies/broadcasts of the other app)?

Can the PWA call intents, be called as an intent, etc? What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 25):

#### Sending Share Intent (via Web Share API)

At the [Chrome Dev Summit 2016](https://youtu.be/YJwrBbze_Ec?t=28m6s), the team announced the [Web Share API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/navigator-share), which allows PWAs to invoke the native sharing capabilities of the device (e.g., see [Android demo video](https://youtu.be/YJwrBbze_Ec?t=29m11s)) in response to a user gesture (e.g., by clicking a link; cannot be automatic). The API is very new and behind an origin trial.

The following example click-handler invokes the Share Intent, which brings up the native app picker to share data with a user-chosen app. Passing a URL (optional) allows that app to provide a link to the user e.g. for a detail view.

```js
function onClick() {
    navigator.share({
        title: document.title,
        text: "Hello World",
        url: window.location.href
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch(error => console.log('Error sharing:', error));
}
```

#### Sending Android Intents from Chrome

It's possible to send an Android intent from a PWA with [intent URLs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). This method also requires a user gesture to initiate (e.g., by clicking a link; cannot be automatic).

The intent syntax is:

```
intent:
   HOST/URI-path // Optional host 
   #Intent; 
      package=[string]; 
      action=[string]; 
      category=[string]; 
      component=[string]; 
      scheme=[string]; 
   end;
```

For example, clicking this anchor tag launches the ZX Barcode Scanner app:

```html
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

#### Receiving Android Intents

I found nothing on PWAs receiving intents or broadcast messages from native apps. I don't think it's possible. **Update:** This is now possible with [Web Share Targets](https://web.dev/web-share-target/).

Comment: RE: receiving intents, is that related to https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks#android_intent_filters ?