# Is it possible to call PWA from native application?

Tags: native, progressive-web-apps

Does PWA support custom url scheme ?

We are going to develop PWA.
This PWA calls native application with custom url scheme on iPad.
And native application called by PWA will call back to PWA after process is completed.
But I don't know how to call back PWA from native application.

Would you please give us your advice ?

Comment: Hi, Have you got any updates on this? Is it possible to pass parameters from PWA to native iOS apps and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PWAs are really some kind of Web Apps that look more like a native app. They are reliable, they load faster than any normal websites and apps, they are fast, they interact with the user more naturally, and they are engaging that is they can send push messages, feels like a natural app.

You can not call a PWA from a native app, but you can call a native app from a PWA as of now. Which means that you can't pass some data from PWA to a native app then return the processed data to the PWA back. Remember that PWAs are really some web apps. That works on some websites say some-url.com!

Comment: I think you meant to say the opposite of what you wrote down. You CAN NOT call a PWA from a native app, but you CAN call a native app from a PWA.

Comment: @Jordi Bruin : You are right.  I edited the answer to show the correct way around.

Answer (score 4):

Communications beyond just invoking the PWA is not possible as of now. If you are planning to do things like call Native app 1 to calculate some value and pass it back to PWA, its currently not possible. Once the PWA is added to the home screen in Android, when any app tries to access the URL of the app(say https://example.com/myapp) and if thats with in the scope of your PWA, PWA will be opened. But there is no way to pass in data in any direction.

**Update:** Just to clarify. We can actually call Native app from PWA using [Intent URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40933494/1057093).

Same way, we can call PWA from Native app/web browser URLs by simply invoking a URL which is in the scope of your PWA. Android will open your PWA homepage(cant open a specific page though). Support in iOS and other browser/platform may vary.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!

Comment: The accepted answer mentions "You can not call a PWA from a native app" but you have written that "we can call PWA from Native app". One of these is false. 
Also, if I can open a deep link from PWA to a native app, process that url U1 in native app, create a new url U2 in native app, with new info and open the url U2 using PWA, it provides a two way communication as clearly contradicted by the accepted answer.
Can you confirm?