# How can I make a PWA application access other native app?

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a PWA application running on both iOS and Android. There is a requirement on the app to support navigation. I know it is hard to support the navigation on a PWA app what I want to achieve is that to popup a dialog to ask users to open a native app for navigation such as `google map` or `apple map` etc. How can I do that through PWA application?

Another use case is that how I can pass additional information to the native app? For example, I create a native app and want it to be open from a PWA app. How can PWA app open my native app and pass a json data.

Answer (score 5):

For opening native maps apps, use URL schemes.

For example if you want to open the Apple maps app focussing the apple headquarter, use this URL: `http://maps.apple.com/?address=1,Infinite+Loop,Cupertino,California`.
If you open such link in the Safari browser, a popup opens which asks to open the Apple maps native app. ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1))

For the Google maps app, it is similar. You just have to use Google maps links like this: `https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=Infinite+Loop,Cupertino,California`. ([source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide))

Comment: Can I pass extra information to the app? For example, I created a native app and want to open that app from PWA. So I need to open a native app with some json object.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON Derulo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5470544/json-derulo)'s answer successfully answers your question regarding local map links. However I believe [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40933494/385687) will answer the second half of your question on how to pass information to native apps on the device. In short, you'll want to use an Android intent to pass any information you want to send.