# Receiving Intents into Progressive Web App

Tags: android-intent, progressive-web-apps

I'm attempting to build a stock management app for our business. I don't have much experience building native apps so I have started looking into progressive web apps. We are using Zebra TC devices with data wedge installed which will allow me to output barcode readings to android apps through the intent system.

Is it possible to receive Android intents into a progressive web app as its not native?

for example if I scan a barcode I want to open the web app on a page that will log the item. So I scan the barcode then it sends the data to example.com/items/scan?barcode="Scanned Barcode".

I have create a profile to output the barcode to the built-in Android intents. However this wont open the web app to this page it only opens the chrome app to the page which isn't the desired response.

Intent:
`android.intent.action.MAIN`

Intent Category:
`android.internet.category.LAUNCHER`

Then used the formatting to append the URL to the scanned barcode.

EG `https://example.com/items/scan?barcode=01234567`

The above will open a new Chrome page to the URL but not the web app that i've installed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks#android_intent_filters), it looks like this should work, but maybe the barcode app's intents are the wrong category?

> When a Progressive Web App is installed on Android, it will register a set of intent filters for all URLs within the scope of the app. When a user clicks on a link that is within the scope of the app, the app will be opened, rather than opening within a browser tab.
>
> Consider the following partial manifest.json:
>
> ```
> "start_url": "/",
> "display": "standalone",
> ```
>
> When a web app using it is
>   launched from the app launcher, it would open https://example.com/ as
>   a standalone app, without any browser chrome.
>
> The [generated] WebAPK would include the following intent filters:
>
> ```
> <intent-filter>
>   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>   <data
>     android:scheme="https"
>     android:host="example.com"
>     android:pathPrefix="/" />
> </intent-filter>
> ```
>
> If the user clicks on a link within an installed app to https://example.com/read, it would be
>   caught by the intent and opened in the Progressive Web App.

I don't know much about Android, but can you change to a barcode scanner that generates `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`?

Answer (score -1):

"Is it possible to **receive** Android intents into a progressive web app as its not native?"

No.

Ref: [PWA interoperability with Android apps/services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858803/pwa-interoperability-with-android-apps-services)